# What is the structure of IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

```
using (var nosql = new DbHelper("Feed")) 
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    nosql.CollectionName = "rawhi";
    var x = nosql.GetRecords<Event>(p => true, 0, 1000000);
    //GridView1.DataSource = x;
    //GridView1.DataBind();
    watch.Stop();
    long milliseconds = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Response.Write(milliseconds);
}
```

`x` is a variable of type `IQueryable`.

When I run this code the result is: `0`

So I'm wondering if the data is stored in the `x` var or not?

Comment: Try `x.ToList();` before `watch.Stop()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query will be lazily evaluated, so until something tries to enumerate the results, the query is not actually executed or the results returned. In your code example you have set the query up, but you have not actually run it. If you put your databinding code back in, that will actually enumerate the result and so execute it.

For testing purposes you can force enumeration as follows:

```
x.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You only set up the piping so to speak - you now will be able to retrieve the results through `x` but they are lazily retrieved only when you do it.

You could retrieve them one by one:

```
foreach(var item in x)
{
  //do something
}
```

Sometimes its advantageous to eagerly retrieve data, in that case you can use `ToList()` which enumerates all the results internally and puts the result set in x - then you can measure how long it would take:

```
  var x = nosql.GetRecords<Event>(p => true, 0, 1000000).ToList();
```